# Failure to understand Don Zagier equality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, p-adic-number-theory

In an article in *American Mathematical Monthly*, Don Zagier states the following equality
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1t^r(1-t)^r dt\right)x^r=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+xt+xt^2}$$
however I don't understand how he obtains a positive  $xt$ on the denominator instead of a negative.
The article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324560?seq=1.

Here is my working.
Let
\begin{equation*}
   S= \sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1t^r(1-t)^r dt\right)x^r=\int_0^1\left(\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty t^r(1-t)^rx^r\right)dt.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{align*}
 \sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty t^r(1-t)^rx^r=\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty(xt(1-t))^r&=1+xt(1-t)+(xt(1-t))^2+\ldots\\
    &=\frac{1}{1-xt(1-t)}=\frac{1}{1-xt+xt^2}.    
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
    S=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1-xt+xt^2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: This is hard to answer without going through the technique.  The specifc part that you don't understand should be included in your question.

Comment: Maybe it is an unimportant misprint.

Comment: I believe we should find a factor of $(-1)^r$ in the series terms yes

Comment: Indeed, when you sum up the geometric progression for say $|x|<4$ then you obtain the integral of $(1-xt+xt^2)^{-1}.$

Comment: Seems reasonable enough to me. For a couple of particular values of $x$ I tried numerically, your version agrees with the integral and the result you mention does not.